# Self-Join to get First Record and Record on Last day of Month

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table that looks like this.  The table is generated by pinging each account in the system everyday to record an 'mrr' amount.  The 'mrr' account is 0 if the account is not paying.  It records a value when the account starts paying.  If the account cancels, the mrr recorded goes back to 0.

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-----+
| paylog_id | account_id |    date    | mrr |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----+
|      1001 |         99 | 2016-01-15 |   0 |
|      1002 |         99 | 2016-01-16 |   0 |
|      1003 |         99 | 2016-01-17 |   0 |
|      1004 |         99 | 2016-01-18 |   0 |
|      1005 |         99 | 2016-01-19 |   0 |
|      1006 |         99 | 2016-01-20 |  25 |
|      1007 |         99 | 2016-01-21 |  25 |
|      1008 |         99 | 2016-01-22 |  25 |
|      1009 |         99 | 2016-01-23 |  25 |
|      1010 |         99 | 2016-01-24 |  25 |
|      1011 |         99 | 2016-01-25 |  25 |
|      1012 |         99 | 2016-01-26 |  25 |
|      1013 |         99 | 2016-01-27 |  25 |
|      1014 |         99 | 2016-01-28 |   0 |
|      1015 |         99 | 2016-01-29 |   0 |
|      1016 |         99 | 2016-01-30 |   0 |
|      1017 |         99 | 2016-01-31 |   0 |
|      1018 |         99 | 2016-02-01 |   0 |
|      1019 |         79 | 2016-02-23 | 255 |
|      1020 |         79 | 2016-02-24 | 255 |
|      1021 |         79 | 2016-02-25 | 255 |
|      1022 |         79 | 2016-02-26 | 255 |
|      1023 |         79 | 2016-02-27 | 255 |
|      1024 |         79 | 2016-02-28 |  50 |
|      1025 |         79 | 2016-02-29 |  25 |
|      1026 |         79 | 2016-03-01 |  25 |
|      1027 |         79 | 2016-03-02 |  27 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----+
```

I need to know 2 pieces of information-

1. What is the amount on the very first date the account starts paying?
2. What is the amount on the last day of the month of the month in which the account started paying?

The result in the above example should be:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-----+------------+-------------+------------+------+
| paylog_id | account_id |    date    | mrr | paylog_id1 | account_id1 |   date1    | mrr1 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----+------------+-------------+------------+------+
|      1006 |         99 | 2016-01-20 |  25 |       1017 |          99 | 2016-01-31 |    0 |
|      1018 |         79 | 2016-02-23 | 255 |       1024 |          79 | 2016-02-29 |   25 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----+------------+-------------+------------+------+
```

I know I can get the first payment date using this query:

```
SELECT
 a.paylog_id,
 a.account_id,
 a.date,
 a.mrr
FROM
 ds_paylogs a
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
  account_id,
  min(date) mdate, mrr
 FROM
  ds_paylogs b
where b.mrr >0
 GROUP BY
  account_id
) b ON a.account_id = b.account_id
AND a.date = b.mdate
```

Result:

```
+------+----+----------+-----+
| 1006 | 99 | 20-01-16 | 25  |
+------+----+----------+-----+
| 1018 | 79 | 23-02-16 | 255 |
+------+----+----------+-----+
```

Separately, I can get the last day of the month on the first payment date using:

```
SELECT
 a.paylog_id,
 a.account_id,
 a.date,
 a.mrr
FROM
 ds_paylogs a
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
  account_id,
  LAST_DAY(min(date)) mdate, mrr
 FROM
  ds_paylogs b
where b.mrr >0
 GROUP BY
  account_id
) b ON a.account_id = b.account_id
AND a.date = b.mdate
```

Result:

```
+------+----+----------+----+
| 1017 | 99 | 31-01-16 | 0  |
+------+----+----------+----+
| 1024 | 79 | 29-02-16 | 25 |
+------+----+----------+----+
```

I want to join these two results together into one view.  I am stuck on how to do that?

Any advice on how to do that or how to simplify my queries is very much appreciated.

Update: Doing the below gets me what I need. However, it seems like there should be a more elegant solution to this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.paylog_id,
            a.account_id,
            a.date,
            a.mrr
        FROM
            ds_paylogs a
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                account_id,
                min(date) mdate,
                mrr
            FROM
                ds_paylogs b
            WHERE
                b.mrr > 0
            GROUP BY
                account_id
        ) b ON a.account_id = b.account_id
        AND a.date = b.mdate
    ) q
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        a.paylog_id,
        a.account_id,
        a.date,
        a.mrr
    FROM
        ds_paylogs a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            account_id,
            LAST_DAY(min(date)) mdate,
            mrr
        FROM
            ds_paylogs b
        WHERE
            b.mrr > 0
        GROUP BY
            account_id
    ) b ON a.account_id = b.account_id
    AND a.date = b.mdate
) r ON q.account_id = r.account_id
```

Comment: You have some duplicate `paylog_id` values in your example table. Is that correct?

Comment: @OllieJones No that is not correct. I have updated the table to reflect that. Error on my part when creating the sample table.